# React Native FileSystem file could not be read? What the Blob?

Tags: react-native, websocket, blob

I am trying to send an audio file recorded using expo-av library to my server using web sockets.

Websocket will allow me to only send String, ArrayBuffer or Blob. I spent whole day trying to find out  how to convert my .wav recording into a blob but without success. I tried to use expo-file-system method FileSystem.readAsStringAsync to read the filed as a string but I get an error that the file could not be read. How is that possible? I passed it the correct URI (using recording.getURI()).

I tried to re-engineer my approach to use fetch and FormData post request with the same URI and audio gets sent correctly. But I really would like to use WebSockets so that later I could try to make it stream the sound to the server in real time instead of recording it first and then sending it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ... But I can't find a way to read the blob itself
// this is from my code ...

```
    let recording = Audio.Recording ;
    const info = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(recording.getURI() || "");
    console.log(`FILE INFO: ${JSON.stringify(info)}`);

    // get the file as a blob
    const response = await fetch(info.uri);
    const blob = await response.blob(); // slow - Takes a lot of time
```